# Image Processing in Metro Application

Tags: c#, matlab, image-processing, microsoft-metro

I need to do some image processing in a Windows 8 metro application. I have written some functions in MATLAB for that. Is there a way I can integrate them in my application? I am kinda lost here. Can anyone suggest something about this? I would be grateful.

P.S: In my MATLAB program I am detecting face shape and skin tone.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, why not? Just re-implement your Matlab code in C# or C++. Do you have a specific question?

You can use computer vision libraries like OpenCV (or the EmguCV C# wrapper) or AForge.NET.

Comment: Can you please shed some light on how to reimplement it in C#? Like how can I use canny edge detector in C#?

Comment: I read about using OpenCV and I saw a lot of problems regarding using this library in Metro applications because it is not supported or something like that. I will look into others you have mentioned.. Thanks

Comment: You can use OpenCV from Metro applications, even from JavaScript Windows 8 TIFKAM applications (using Emgucv).

Comment: can you give me a link or something that tells how can i get stareted? I have never used OpenCV before and I am unable to find a guide to use it in metro apps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [lightweight image processing sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/340859/Metro-Style-Lightweight-Image-Processing). I think it's better to check this sample, it might be helpful to you. Please note the article is bit older so it must be updated by author.

Comment: Thanks for pointing but I think I need some more complex functions.